# Replacing selected xml nodes using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-parsing

Is there a better way to remove selected nodes from XML using Javascript? I see that `removeChild()` method can be used. But I don't want to traverse through the entire XML tree right to the bottom where the to-be replaced node is stuck. In simple, I should be able to fly right to my node of interest and replace its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

$.parseXML("well formed xml document").find('css selector to find element to remove').remove()

Answer (score 0):

What about using [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_xpath.asp)? It should be implemented in every modern browser.